# How can I fix the 'Expected state to include' error when using action.devices.EXECUTE with a thermostat device on Google Home?

Tags: java

Test skill error, error message as follows

```java
Expected state to include: {"thermostatTemperatureSetpoint":20}, actual state: {}: expected false to be true
The data returned by action.devices.EXECUTE is 

{
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "ids": [
          "2-3ff7c353d55cfa6fa6d5a8e8facad017-32dcfe7c1"
        ],
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "states": {
          "online": true,
          "thermostatMode": "on"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "requestId": "17484325286169092632"
}
```

Attempts to modify the return structure did not work